# Is Object created before or after method calls?

Tags: c#

I have three different databases that I need to check that I am connected to. This is what I originally have, which works perfectly fine.

```
public async Task<ServiceAvailabilityDTO> ServiceAvailabilityStatus()
{
    return new ServiceAvailabilityDTO
    {
        IsDb1Online = await IsDb1Available(),
        IsDb2Online = IsDb2Available(),
        IsDb3Online = await IsDb3Available()
    };
}

private async Task<bool> IsDb1Available()
{
    var count = await _db1Service.GetDbCount();
    if (count > 0)
        return true;

    return false;
}

private bool IsDb2Available()
{
    if (_db2Service.GetDbCount() > 0)
        return true;

    return false;
}

private async Task<bool> IsDb3Available()
{
    var pong = await _db3Provider.PingDb();
    if(pong.Success == true && pong.Version != null)
        return true;

    return false;
}
```

Now however, I need to log **exception messages** in my DTO for each DB check.

```
public async Task<ServiceAvailabilityDTO> ServiceAvailabilityStatus()
{
    return new ServiceAvailabilityDTO
    {
        IsDb1Online = await IsDb1Available(),
        IsDb2Online = IsDb2Available(),
        IsDb3Online = await IsDb3Available(this) // This is an example. I want to pass the reference of **ServiceAvailabilityDTO** to **IsDb3Available**
    };
}

private async Task<bool> IsDb3Available(ServiceAvailabilityDTO availability)
{
    try
    {
        var pong = await _db3Provider.PingDb();
        if(pong.Success == true && pong.Version != null)
            return true;

        return false;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        var exceptionMessage = e.Message;
        if (e.InnerException != null)
        {
            // This is what I hope to put into the object reference
            exceptionMessage = String.Join("\n", exceptionMessage, e.InnerException.Message);
            availability.db3Exception = exceptionMessage ;
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

My question is;

1. Can I keep my return method the same as in the first example, and pass the object reference to each method to store the exception and still return my **bool** value.
2. Or does the object not get created until all of the method calls have happened, and then create the object with the returned values?

> I know I could just create the object normally and pass it in each
>   method call, but it is specifically this way of doing it that has
>   inspired me to ask this question, purely to be informed and learn
>   from.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cannot do it like this because in the context of what you're doing `this` does not refer to the object you're populating, it refers to the object containing the method you're calling.

```
public async Task<ServiceAvailabilityDTO> ServiceAvailabilityStatus()
{
    return new ServiceAvailabilityDTO
    {
        IsDb1Online = await IsDb1Available(),
        IsDb2Online = IsDb2Available(),
        IsDb3Online = await IsDb3Available(this) // here 'this' does NOT ref to ServiceAvailabilityDTO
    };
}
```

There is no keyword which *does* refer to `ServiceAvailabilityDTO` either, so you're left with creating the object, and passing it to each method. At this point, I dont think there is much point you returning the boolean either - you may as well set the boolean property in line

```
public async Task<ServiceAvailabilityDTO> ServiceAvailabilityStatus()
{
    var sa = new ServiceAvailabilityDTO();
    await CheckDb1Available(sa);
    CheckDb2Available(sa);
    await CheckDb3Available(sa);
    return sa;
}
```

(Note I've renamed the methods from `Is*` to `Check*` as the former implies a return boolean, the latter implies something going on inline.)

Comment: I was thinking I would have to do it this way alright. Was just curious to know if it was possible. Thanks.